# How do i eliminate a value from dropdown if it is auto populated

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, drop-down-menu, default

My jsp dropdown list looks like

```
    <select name="dropdown1"
            name="authority_name">
            <option value="DEFAULT_VALUE"> <c:out value="${user[1]}" /></option>
            <option value="ROLE_USER">USER</option>
            <option value="ROLE_INSTRUCTOR">INSTRUCTOR</option>
            <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">ADMINISTRATOR /></option>
        </select>
```

Now, if i have the default value populated as USER i would like to eliminate it from the drop down list and only display the other 2 options along with default value. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Ideally you would just remove it from the .jsp.  Is that not an option?

Comment: I need the default value because it's a value from the database that is populated as user, instructor or admin depending on the current role of the person. So, if the default value of some x user is admin now i don't want to dipslay the admin for that user drop down as it would be repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove options of `USER`, but keep all other options including `INSTRUCTOR` and `ADMINISTRATOR`, you can use a jstl if statement to only render the default option if the variable is not `USER`.

Something like this would work:

```
<select name="dropdown1"
        name="authority_name">
    <c:if test=${user[1] != 'USER'}><option value="DEFAULT_VALUE"><c:out value="${user[1]}" /></option></c:if>
    <option value="ROLE_USER">USER</option>
    <option value="ROLE_INSTRUCTOR">INSTRUCTOR</option>
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">ADMINISTRATOR /></option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps.